# How to set two rows in mobile and single row in desktop?

Tags: html, css

I want single row in desktop and two rows in mobile, it works fines in mobile too but no enough space, if put col-xs-50, it will not get change, it remain same, please check the [picture i have attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1iNf.jpg). In code I gave only 2 single features, but it has 4 single features

```
<div class="row">
    <!--=======  single feature  =======-->

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-50 col-md-20 single-feature d-flex">
        <div class="image">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-cart"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h5>${orderNumToDash}&nbsp;Orders</h5>
            <p>Recent orders</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--=======  End of single feature  =======-->
    <!--=======  single feature  =======-->

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-50 col-md-20 single-feature d-flex">
        <div class="image">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-add"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h5>${customerNumber}&nbsp; Customers</h5>
            <p>No of Customers</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--=======  End of single feature  =======-->
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vNe7ODy   ,please check the picture, in code i gave only 2 single features,but it has 4 single features , see the picture

Comment: If you want to add something to your question, please do so by editing the question, not by a comment. It is very difficult to read if the information is spread across multiple posts.

Comment: i cant post image because i dont have reputation to post it , thats why i added here , anyway ,did you see  the picture , please solve my problem